# bind9 DNS works predictably for OSX machines but not for Windows machines

Tags: apache2, windows-8, dns, macosx

I have set up a DNS server using bind9. The purpose is to create a zone so that developers can browse to their work at `something.dev.di` where `something` could be anything as long as there is a matching virtual host in the Apache2 configuration.

This has worked as expected on my OSX machines. But testing it on a Windows 8.1 machine has produced confusing results.

I have one virtual host where the server name setting is `example_site.dev.di` - this works perfectly well on the OSX machine but on the Windows machine I get 'Server not found'.

So I did a bit of random testing and found several addresses that worked on OSX but not on Windows.

For example, on OSX test.dev.di works, it displays the default web site as expected because there is no equivalent virtual host. On Windows it fails.

Other examples where it works on OSX but not Windows:

`something.dev.di` (but `anything.dev.di` does work), `testing.dev.di`, `a.dev.di` (but `y.dev.di` does work), in fact all single characters fail except 't' and 'y' and the numbers 6 and 8.

Here's the only changes that I made to the bind9 config:

I added the following to `/etc/bind/named.conf.local` which was otherwise empty bar some comments:

```
zone "dev.di" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.dev.di";
};
```

I created a file called `/etc/bind/db.dev.di` and entered the following:

```
;
; BIND data file for development server
;
$TTL 14400
@ IN  SOA dev.di. root.dev.di. (
            2014072001   ; Serial
                 86400   ; Refresh
                  7200   ; Retry
               3600000   ; Expire
                 86400 ) ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@ IN  NS  dev.di.
@ IN  A 192.168.1.201
* IN  A 192.168.1.201
@ IN  AAAA  ::1
```

I am at a loss as to how to troubleshoot this because the success/fail seems so random.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm ... baffling ... I have found a way around this problem. I still don't understand the original issue but it went away when I did the following:

I had set the DNS server on each machine that I was using to test from because I didn't want to upset the 'Super User' who was hitting the internet with full force this morning. By super user I mean my wife.

Anyway, when she wandered away from her machine I set the DNS server on the router and removed references to it from all local machines and restarted everything.

Now it works. And my wife never even noticed me bringing the network down for a bit. All round good result I say!

Comment: What would happen If she ever know this?

Comment: I don't know, it didn't happen. :)